# Toggle classes from different divs issue

Tags: jquery, selector

So I have a page that displays multiple "posts" that include "comments". My code:

```
<div class="post">
    This is a post
    <span class="toggleComments">Hide/Show Comments</span>
    <div class="comment">This is a comment</div>
</div>
<div class="post">
    This is another post
    <span class="toggleComments">Hide/Show Comments</span>
    <div class="comment">This is another comment</div>
    <div class="comment">This is a third comment</div>
</div>
```

So here is my problem: I have a span with the class `toggleComments` included which "toggles" the comment div. I have achieved this with:

```
$('.toggleComments').click(function(){
    $('.comment').toggle();
});
```

The thing is that by clicking the link, the `.comment` div form ALL the comments hides/appears, is there a way to make it so the comments from the same post toggle the effect, and not the comments from all the posts?

EDIT: Updated with the .toggleComments line

Comment: You would need to show us where `.toggleComments` is in your HTML relative to the HTML you have shown us.

Comment: Ugh, RTFD: http://api.jquery.com. Specifically: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL with the jquery docs as awesome as they are, couldn't pretty much every question in the jquery section have that comment ;)

Comment: the .toggleComments is above the .comment class and inside the .post class. I've read the api and taken an course on jquery as well, but this bugs me out a lot

Comment: @Systemfreak Add that class to your example in the html please.

Comment: sorry for that, i added the class

Comment: That's lame. I answered first, correct and even worked with the OP to update there example.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uzadoy/3/edit Just a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `.toggleComments` is inside of the same `.post` that you want to toggle the comment on, you would find the parent `.post` and then inside of that find the appropriate comment to toggle:

```
$('.toggleComments').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".post").find(".comment").toggle();
});
```

As you can see from the other answers, there are many approaches to finding the `.comment` objects in the same containing div.  The advantage of doing it this way rather than referencing siblings is that it will find them anywhere in the common `.post` parent even if the layout of the HTML is tweaked somewhat in the future.  I prefer to make this type of code as robust as possible against future HTML tweaks as long as it doesn't compromise anything important.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I've been waiting with this answer for the OP to actually disclose where the `".toggleComments"` item is.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.toggleComments').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.comment').toggle();
});
```

**Updated** to reflect OP's updated html.

Comment: I would have used `.closest()` and not `.parents()`

Comment: tried it but didn't work, the other way with the .closest() worked good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7QuB/2/)

```
$('.toggleComments').click(function(){
    var thisParent = $(this).parents('.post');
    thisParent.find('.comment').toggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uzadoy/2/edit)**

If you have something like:

```
<div class="post">
    This is a post
    <div class="toggleComments">SHOW COMMENTS</div>
    <div class="comment">This is a comment</div>
</div>
```

...than this should help.

```
$('.toggleComments').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.comment').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because all of your ".comment" and ".toggleComments" are the same selector.

If you change these to be unique they will work. i.e:

```
<div class="post-1">
    This is a post
    <a class="toggle-1">Toggle Comments</a>
    <div class="comment-1">This is a comment</div>
</div>
<div class="post-2">
    This is a post
    <a class="toggle-2">Toggle Comments</a>
    <div class="comment-2">This is a comment</div>
</div>
$('.toggle-1').click(function(){
    $('.comment-1').toggle();
});
$('.toggle-2').click(function(){
    $('.comment-2').toggle();
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Uh9hJ/

EDIT: Using siblings is a much better btw, this guy has it right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10115482/864488